# Java: using a string to stop a while loop and it is consumed by following scanner input

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am taking an intro programing class with Java as the language. The assignment we are working on is bedeviling me. I have a *while* loop asking for numerical values, that terminates when a string value is entered, i.e.

```
while (sc.hasNextDouble())
{...}
```

This is followed by another Scanner input, which is using

```
if (sc.hasNextLine())
```

The problem is I am using a string to terminate the top *while* loop, which is then immediately consumed by the Scanner. I attempted using an if/else statement for the top loop with an explicit *break;* statement, but that did not work. No matter what I do it is still being passed on. How should I approach this? Any pointers appreciated.

EDIT: By request, here is some of the  actual code. Keep in mind this is for an arbitrary class assignment, so it may not make tons of sense.

```
 //Request user input
        System.out.print("Please enter multiple double values. Enter q or any non double value to quit.");
        double doubleValue = 0.00; //declare doubleValue variable (for each entered double value)
        double sum = 0.00; //declare starting sum value variable at 0.00
        double doubleAverage = 0.00; //declare average of doubles variable
        //declare largest double value variable as MIN_VALUE to ensure any entered value is larger
        double largestDouble = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        //declare smallest double value variable as MAX_VALUE to ensure any entered value is smaller
        double smallestDouble = Double.MAX_VALUE; //declare smallest double value variable
        int count = 0; //set starting count

        while (sc.hasNextDouble())
        {
          doubleValue = sc.nextDouble();
          //System.out.print("Please enter another double value. Enter -1 to stop entering values.");
          sum = sum + doubleValue;
          count++;
          }

        /*
        * This section prompts the user for their first name and printd it in reverse.
        */

        System.out.print("Please enter your first name:");
        String fName = ""; //declare fName variable before requesting input
        if (sc.hasNext())
        {
          fName = sc.next();
```

…

After this the String value used to terminate the while loop I used for the if statement at the end.

Comment: can you update post with what you did so far and with minimal example

Comment: Just take all input as text and then check to see if you should quit

Comment: I cannot take input as text, there are requirements to take multiple doubles as input in the upper Scanner.

Comment: Why can you not convert the `String` to a `Double`?

Comment: Because this is a class assignment, there are some arbitrary restrictions on what we are supposed to do. We have to request multiple doubles, the perform some computations, then from there request the user's name. The inputs are supposed to be validated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to not pass the data from the `sc` scanner is to create a new Scanner Object. Lets call this one `scan`. This way when you refer to `scan` it won't know the `sc` scanners input from earlier.

In your `if` statement, you would refer to the `scan` scanner instead of the `sc` scanner.

The reason the data was being passed from the `while` loop to your `if` statement is because they both referred to the same object and when you called `sc.hasNext()` it read the last thing that you inputted into the console.

Comment: I have updated it see if this works. Your use of an if statement is correct. I read your question wrong the first time.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, and more importantly it helped me realize what was actually going on. The type of thing a novice won't typically consider! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the input as String and then convert it

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

String in = sc.nextLine();

while (!in.equals("q")) {

    try {
        Double d = Double.valueOf(in);
        // do whatever you like with d 
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("oi, that is not a double");
    }
    in = sc.nextLine();

}
```

Comment: Some of this includes things we have not covered, but it gives me a framework to think about. I have not tried the method of checking for a value with ! and terminating if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Another valid option provided by my instructor was using a dummy variable to consume the Scanner input, i.e.something like:

`String fName = sc.next(); // Consume the Q or q here`.